# Multilevel Pandas Iteration of Complex Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multilevel-analysis

My data appears like below, which is a multilevel pandas dataframe, which I'm trying to run some operations on; but need help accessing specific levels...

```
    print(df.head())

                    FB                                      AMZN                  \
              open    high     low   close    volume    open    high     low   
date                                                                           
2017-01-03  116.03  117.84  115.51  116.86  20663912  757.92  758.76  747.70   
2017-01-04  117.55  119.66  117.29  118.69  19630932  758.39  759.68  754.20   
2017-01-05  118.86  120.95  118.32  120.67  19492150  761.55  782.40  760.26   
2017-01-06  120.98  123.88  120.03  123.41  28545263  782.36  799.44  778.48   
2017-01-09  123.55  125.43  123.04  124.90  22880360  798.00  801.77  791.77  

                             ...    GOOG                                   \
             close   volume  ...    open    high     low   close   volume   
date                         ...                                            
2017-01-03  753.67  3521066  ...  778.81  789.63  775.80  786.14  1657268   
2017-01-04  757.18  2510526  ...  788.36  791.34  783.16  786.90  1072958   
2017-01-05  780.45  5830068  ...  786.08  794.48  785.02  794.02  1335167   
2017-01-06  795.99  5986234  ...  795.26  807.90  792.20  806.15  1640170   
2017-01-09  796.92  3446109  ...  806.40  809.97  802.83  806.65  1274645   

              TSLA                                    
              open    high     low   close    volume  
     date                                                  
     2017-01-03  214.86  220.33  210.96  216.99   5923254  
2017-01-04  214.75  228.00  214.31  226.99  11213471  
2017-01-05  226.42  227.48  221.95  226.75   5911695  
2017-01-06  226.93  230.31  225.45  229.01   5527893  
2017-01-09  228.97  231.92  228.00  231.28   3979484  

[5 rows x 25 columns]
```

Also, more info on the levels:

```
df.columns.levels

FrozenList([['FB', 'AMZN', 'NFLX', 'GOOG', 'TSLA'], ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']])
```

I would like to iterate through this Dataframe, one stock ticker at a time, and perform an operation on the 'close' column.  For example,

`````
for stock_ticker in df:
    print(stock_ticker) #print stock name
    if 'close' <= 100:   # if the 'close' column for the specific stock ticker is <= 100
        print(stock_ticker is less than or equal to 100)
    else:
        print(stock_ticker is greater than 100)````
`````

I'm looking to do more complex things with this; but, this code would get me there.

Answer (score 2):

On MultiIndex to access a certain value of a level, the simple way is using `pd.IndexSlice` with `loc`. In your case do as follows (Note: I use only `FB` and `AMZN` from your sample)

```
ix = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[:, (ix[:],'close')]
```

Or

```
df1 = df.loc[:, ix[:,'close']]

Out[88]:
                FB    AMZN
             close   close
0
2017-01-03  116.86  753.67
2017-01-04  118.69  757.18
2017-01-05  120.67  780.45
2017-01-06  123.41  795.99
2017-01-09  124.90  796.92
```

So, `df1` is the `close` column of each `ticker`. Just do all your logic on `df1`.